# How can I use taper on a mesh?

Tags: modifiers

I have a wing shape extruded in Blender, so what I have now is some sort of an airfoil along the z axis (0 to positive z) wiht the blunt edge to the right (positive x) and the sharp edge at the origin (0 x) (the rear side).

I want the rear side (z in origin) to be shorter than the front (z at positive x), that is, that the 3d mesh is tapered from the front to the rear.

However, when I apply the simple deform modifier and pick "taper" it deforms the model both in x and y (and not z) at only one side (positive z).

So the tapering is going in the wrong direction at the wrong place.

I added an empty to use as origin for the modifier, but it changed nothing. Can someone help?

note: I found a way that said I can use "o" and simply move the vertices at the end of the airfoil inwards and then the next ones would also move a litte bit, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot? I was also thinking along the line of Proportional Edit with the O key, but if that doesn't work then maybe the geometry might provide a clue. With proportional edit, you coudl try different fallof types and use the mmb to adjust the range of influence.

Comment: As @CraigDJones said, some picture of it may help. But what about using a lattice?

Comment: Right, here is the image: I did this now by pulling each vertex manually in the (hopefully correct) position and then linking the opposing vertices with F, then the neighbouring edges with F again.

Lots of work. Hope this can be done easier next time, maybe with tapering.

http://i67.tinypic.com/288zcpt.png